# lost attribute after adding column to pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I like to add attributes to pandas DataFrame columns, for example to manage labels or units.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [5, 6]], columns=['A', 'B'])
df['A'].units = 'm/s'
```

Calling the units of column (with `df['A'].units`) returns `m/s`.

However, the attribute gets lost after any DataFrame to Series operation, such as adding a new column:

```
df['C'] = [3, 8]
df['A'].units
```

> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'units'

Is there an approach to keep the attributes or an alternative to add columns?

Comment: Yes!  Create your own class with the DataFrame as an attribute of your class.  Manage all column attributes in your class.

Comment: @piRSquared , could you give an explicit example? I would like to return the dataframe when the object is called itself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_metadata`, is not part of public API. **Not a stable way** of doing it, still, for now

```
In [8]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [5, 6]], columns=['A', 'B'])

In [9]: df['A']._metadata
Out[9]: ['name']

In [10]: df['A']._metadata.append({'units': 'm/s'})

In [11]: df['C'] = [3, 8]

In [12]: df['A']._metadata
Out[12]: ['name', {'units': 'm/s'}]
```